# Need advice on designing an index to keep track of users that are not subscribed to a document in the system

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lucene, entity-framework-4.1, lucene.net

I have a table for Projects, a table for Documents (with a FK to Projects), and a table for users with a relationship to projects and documents. Users can be subscribers to a document and that is how they have a relationship to the document.

Users are considered team members on a project. A document can only assigned to one project at a time. Only users, from the "Project Team" can be subscribed to a document.

What I am struggling with, in my application, is that admins are able to add users as subscribers to a document. However, the admin can only pick from a list of unsubscribed users. Those unsubscribed users are members of the project team, like I said above.

Right now, I am creating 2 queries on my database to pull all the subscribed users and the entire list of team members. I then compare the list and only pull the team members that are not subscribed.

I am not sure if I should even index this type of data or just pull from the database directly. If I should use an index, this data needs to be updated quickly becuase the admins need that unsubscribed list rather fast.

This is what my query looks like going against Entity Framework 4.1:

```
var currentSubscribers = _subscriptionRepository.Get(s => s.DocumentId == documentId).Select(s => s.Contact).ToList();

                if (projecTeamMembers != null)
                {
                    var availableSubscribers = (projecTeamMembers.Where(
                        p => !(currentSubscribers.Select(c => c.Id)).Contains(p.Id))).ToDictionary(c => c.Id, c=> c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName);
                    return availableSubscribers;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
```

This works great in EF, but I have been thinking of indexing my data using Lucene.Net and need some advice on if I should do this or not.

Comment: What are you using to store your data? If you can put up the query used to pull subscribed users to a document and the query for members, it's likely a combination of the 2 in a join to get the ones not subscribed.

Comment: @Blake, I updated my question with the LINQ query I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to do something like this is, using Lucene.net, is to keep an index of subscribers and an index of all team members. And compare the two. It's faster than pulling form the database each time.

Answer (score 1):

Write this query indide your data repository where you have access to the Database context

```
var q = from m in dbContext.ProjecTeamMembers
        where !(from s in dbContext.Subscribers
                where s.DocumentId == documentId &&
                      s.Contact.Id == p.Id
                select s).Any()
        select m;

var availableSubscribers = q.ToDictionary(m => m.Id, c=> m.LastName + ", " + m.FirstName);
```

Comment: while this is similar to what I am doing above, it doesn't answer my question about whether i should index that data.

Comment: not sure what you mean my index, but creating indexes in the database ob your tables is probably i good idea.

Comment: I was asking about using Lucene as the index and designing it around my scenario.